# Карусель картинок jCarousel

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: установил на сайт jcarousel, в конфиге прописал, чтобы отображал по 10 картинок, а он все равно отображает 3 картинки. Скрин:

[image: img]

Сам конфиг:

```
/*global window, jQuery */
(function($) {
    // Default configuration properties.
    var defaults = {
        vertical: false,
        rtl: false,
        start: 1,
        offset: 1,
        size: 10,
        scroll: 1,
        visible: null,
        animation: 'normal',
        easing: 'swing',
        auto: 0,
        wrap: null,
        initCallback: null,
        setupCallback: null,
        reloadCallback: null,
        itemLoadCallback: null,
        itemFirstInCallback: null,
        itemFirstOutCallback: null,
        itemLastInCallback: null,
        itemLastOutCallback: null,
        itemVisibleInCallback: null,
        itemVisibleOutCallback: null,
        animationStepCallback: null,
        buttonNextHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonPrevHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonNextEvent: 'click',
        buttonPrevEvent: 'click',
        buttonNextCallback: null,
        buttonPrevCallback: null,
        itemFallbackDimension: null
    }, windowLoaded = false;
```

Comment: @mountpoint 
Готово http://jsfiddle.net/uWd8n/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [Документации](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/), за количество отображаемых элементов отвечает параметр **visible**

Минимум:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("yourDivId").jcarousel({
        visible: 10    
    });
})
```

Надо будет и CSS править, но это уже совсем другая история

Answer (score 0):

css править нужно. ширину больше поставь

Comment: Ширина вообще auto стоит. Вся соль в том, что в галереи ооочень много места для картинок.

Comment: @Lektor, кидайте код на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @mountpoint http://pastebin.com/iuBFyfej

Comment: @Lektor, вы знаете что pastebin и jquery  это разные сайты с разным назначением ?

Comment: @Lektor, я просил на http://jsfiddle.net, так как там можно одновременно вставить и HTML и CSS и JS. Это вам и нужно сделать

Comment: @mountpoint http://jsfiddle.net/uWd8n/2/ готово